# Download files starting with specific prefix from SFTP server using Execute Process Task and WinSCP in SSIS

Tags: ssis, sftp, winscp

I am having couple of files present at WinSCP folder location `USERDATA`.
Files present are staring with following names: `ABC_XXXX.txt` and `XYZ_XXXX.txt`.

I am interested in downloading all the files which are starting with `ABC_` prefix only.

Below is my Execute Process Task configuration:

```
Executable- C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe
/log=c:\path\to\log\winscp.log /command "open sftp://username:password@example.com/" "get /USERDATA/User_file.txt C:\User\Local\" "exit"
```

It's running fine when I am downloading a single file. How can we parametrize it to fetch the specific files which starts with prefix `ABC_` only. Is there any way we can set the expression for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [file mask](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask) `ABC_*`:

```
... "get /USERDATA/ABC_* C:\User\Local\" ...
```

Comment: ahhh ! was so simple. :-) Many Thanks